# VSCodeのServer Connector拡張におけるEdit Serverで開いたjsonファイルを変更できない

Tags: vscode

Visual Studio Code 1.55.2
拡張機能：Server Connector 0.23.11
対象サーバ：Wildfly 10.1.0

以上の環境で、VSCodeの「SERVERS」に追加したWildflyに対して、起動時のJVMオプションでヒープの割当メモリを変更したいです。
コンテキストメニューの「Edit Server」から、`tmpServerConnector-wildfly local-16268ZE5fGmk5l7Yu.json`というような名前（名前の後半はランダム？）のファイルが開くのですが、このファイルを修正して保存しても、元に戻ってしまいます。
改めて開き直しても変更されていません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ご覧の通り、保存されました的なメッセージ通知はあるのですが・・・実際は変更できていません。
どなたか対処方法をご存じないでしょうか。

Comment: [`README`](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-server-connector/blob/master/README.md#server-parameters) を見ると `args.override.boolean` を `true` に設定する必要がありそうに思われますが、これを設定しても解消しないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘の方法で解決しました！　報酬を差し上げたいので、ぜひ回答での投稿をお願いします！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args.vm.override.string` や `args.program.override.string` の変更を反映する場合、同時に `args.override.boolean` の値を `true` に設定する必要がある、ようです。

[README.md](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-server-connector/blob/v0_23_11.final/README.md#server-parameters):

> - `"args.vm.override.string"` - allow to override vm arguments. Once you edited this flag, *make sure "args.override.boolean" is set to true before launching your server. Otherwise the server will attempt to auto-generate the launch arguments as it normally does.*
> - `"args.program.override.string"` - allow to override program arguments. Once you edited this flag, *make sure "args.override.boolean" is set to true before launching your server. Otherwise the server will attempt to auto-generate the launch arguments as it normally does.*